# filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP shows Warning: filter_var(): 'regexp' option missing, while this option seems to be present

Tags: php, regex, filter-var

## Background

I'd like to use filter_var() with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP to validate a UUID Version 4 value. I don't want to use preg_match(). I've been searching and testing for hours, and can't get rid of the following problem.

## Input variables

I have three variables:

- `$value`: contains the value submitted by the client/browser
- `$filterType`: is FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP before the code below is executed (otherwise the part of the code isn't executed)
- `$filterOption`: filteroptions, **read from a json configuration file** before the code below is executed

This is how the config file is read and converted into json:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.CONFIG_FILE_QUERYPARAMETER;
if (file_exists($file)) {
   $json = file_get_contents($file);
   if (false !== $json) {
      $config = json_decode($json, false);
```

## Code

`$filterOptionConst` is just defined and used as comparison/working example, and shall be removed when the problem is identified.

```php
$filterOptionConst = array('options' => array('regexp' => '/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/'));

var_dump($filterOption); echo '<br />';       // line 3
var_dump($filterOptionConst); echo '<br />';  // line 4
var_dump($filterOptionConst === $filterOption); echo '<br />'; // line 5

$value1 = filter_var($value, $filterType, $filterOption);           // line 7, warning
$value2 = filter_var($value, $filterType, $filterOptionConst);      // line 8, no warning
$value3 = filter_var($value, $filterType, array('options' => $filterOption['options'])); // line 9, warning
$value4 = filter_var($value, $filterType, array('options' => array('regexp' => $filterOption['options']['regexp'])));  // line 10, no warning
```

## Output

Both line 3 and 4 show the sames output (copy-pasted from actual output; I can't see the difference, at least). So $filterOption and $filterOptionConst should have identical values.

```
array(1) { ["options"]=> array(1) { ["regexp"]=> string(71) "/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/" } }
array(1) { ["options"]=> array(1) { ["regexp"]=> string(71) "/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/" } }
bool(true)
```

But then I get:

```
Warning: filter_var(): 'regexp' option missing in (filename) on line 7
Warning: filter_var(): 'regexp' option missing in (filename) on line 9
```

## What makes me crazy

Lines 7 and 8 call the same function with the same arguments (?), and line 7 throws a warning while line 8 doesn't. The order of the lines (from 7 to 10) don't matter.

Does anyone have any clue what might happen here? Why do line 7 and 9 cause a warning, while 8 (and 10) don't do so? Of course, I'd like to go with line 7, as I use the filter options also for other filters like FILTER_VALIDATE_INT wihout manipulating them. So, the desired result would be a line 7 without warning.

Any help is highly appreciated!

## Update 27.02.2022 (a)

I need to import the configuration file as object structure, so that I can clearly distinct between objects and (indexed) arrays. Thus, I have a function that recursively converts the filter options from objects to associative arrays. The function is tested and seemingly delivers the right output, but somehow filter_var doesn't handle the (equal?) input equally.

```php
function object2array($obj) {
   // only process if it's an object or array being passed to the function
   if (is_object($obj) || is_array($obj)) {
      $result = (array) $obj;
      foreach($result as &$item) {
         //recursively process EACH element regardless of type
         $item = object2array($item);
      }
      return ($result);
   }
   //otherwise (i.e. for scalar values) return without modification
   else {
      return ($obj);
   }
}
```

So, this works,

```
$filteroptions = array('regexp' => $configuration->filter->options->regexp);
```

this works as well,

```
$filteroptions = (array) $configuration->filter->options;
```

and this - with the 'same' output leads to the warning when using filter_var() later on.

```
$filteroptions = object2array($configuration->filter->options);
```

I will further investigate this and update here. Of course, if anyone sees the difference, any hint is still highly appreciated.

## Update 27.02.2022 (b)

I've found the issue, but don't know why this is a problem. The warning disappers when I remove the `&` in the foreach in `object2array()`. The following code (loop without content!) already results in the warning later on.

```
foreach($result as &$item) {
}
```

So, I changed

```
foreach($result as &$item) {
```

to

```
foreach($result as $item) {
```

Of course, I need to change the item, so I changed the loop to

```
foreach($result as $key => $item) {
   $result[$key] = object2array($item);
}
```

Now, I don't have any warnings. But I still don't know why the warnings occured. Does anyone have any hint? Could this be a bug in PHP? Is there any way to debug arrays/objects beyond `var_dump()`?

Comment: How is $filterType being set?  What is the line of code/process that sets that?

Comment: $filterType is retrieved from a function that also reads the config file. According to debugging, it's value ist int(272) (that is FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP). Anyway, all four lines use this variable, so it can hardly make any difference.

Comment: Also, what is the json that is being read, and how is it being read into php?

Comment: Sure it could make a difference, if it isn't actually applying the filter you think it is.

Comment: OK, it actually is 272 in all four cases. I added the code that reads the config file and converts it into json above. The actual code has more than 100 lines, as the config file does many more things.

Comment: Why is your code doing `$config = json_decode($json, false);` ?  You want arrays not php objects.

Comment: You are right, that should be `$config = json_decode($json, true);` I just changed it, but now I need to change plenty of my code. Which is something I have to do, and it will take me more than an hour (3 am here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242442/discussion-between-bogisw-and-gview).

Comment: No worries, perhaps this is the crux of the problem although I can't account for why 2 apparently equivalent variables would produce different results.  With that said, it is possible that it does some typecasting and passes equivalence even though the contents of one is an object and the other is an array.

Comment: Could it be that var_dump shows an array for 'regexp', where it's actually an object? And that even the strict comparison holds both for equal? Edit: No, that's not the case (just tested it)

Comment: Without your input, or a reasonable part of that (not artificially created) it is hard to say exactly what was wrong, when you are mutating a large data structure recursively.  I will offer this fact:  php objects are always passed by reference.  One last thing:  you wrote a recursive function when you could have accomplished the same thing with  `$array = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);`

Comment: Thank you very much gview! So far, I'm using the changed code as workaround. As soon as I have more time, I'll come back and describe the weird effect I observed in a separate question (pointing out the effect in an example), and link the findings here afterwards.

Comment: Your issues likely are based on what your full actual data structure is, and what you are doing with your foreach.  The version of php you are using is important (hopefully you are using php 7 or 8, as 5 is no longer supported.)  The entire handling of arrays was changed between 5 and 7.  It boils down to this:  a foreach operating on an array passes that array by value, and when you change it inside the foreach, you are changing a copy.  It actually is more of a copy-on-write.  That you fixed this by forcing a reference removes any mystery.

Comment: Summary: you changed an element of an array inside a recursive function, reviewed that element when it was changed, and then found that when you tried to use it later, it wasn't what it was inside your function (or inside the foreach) when you changed it.  This is documented internal behavior as I talked about in my prior comment.